# Is a mixture of two strictly proper scoring rules a strictly proper scoring rule?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $A$, $B$ be distinct strictly proper scoring rules. Suppose one has $x$ degrees of confidence in $A$ and (1 - $x$) degrees of confidence in $B$, where $0 \leq x \leq 1$. Is $xA + (1-x)B$ a strictly proper scoring rule?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: The key idea is that since both $A$ and $B$ are proper scoring rules, then the distribution that minimizes the expected loss under both $A$ and $B$ is the same, namely $F$. Since the minimum expected loss of $wA + (1-w)B$ can't be smaller than the minimum of the 2 separate scoring rules, and this is achieved by the distribution $F$. Strictness comes from the fact that any other distribution will give a higher loss for both $A$ and $B$.